# how to output profile information from custom authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created authentication/authorization from scratch. I need help with creating pages that would output the information the user entered when registering and also their profile information. For example where user visits index they will be presented with sign up information (email, password, user, birthday, zip code). Then user can go to /users/ID-HERE to fill out their profile information (height, children, career, religion, ethnicity, etc) and this is the only page where users can edit the profile information. On this page /users/ID-HERE/edit users can modify their registration information.

Now what I don't have is a page that outputs the information user enters, it only shows the edit fields. So what I really want is /users/ID-HERE to show the information user has input (not displaying the edit fields). Then /users/ID-HERE/edit will allow users to modify their profile information. Then create another URL, /users/ID-HERE/account-edit will allow user to modify their registration information. And at some stage I will output the registration information inside the users CP when I build that.

And I'm not understanding how to do this. I only have pages atm that allows you to edit account and profile information, but no separate pages for outputting the information a user  entered in just plain text.

routes.rb:

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :galleries
  resources :photos
```

show.html.erb (profile information):

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h2>Basics</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :height %><br/>
        <%= f.select :feet, [['Feet', nil], '4', '5', '6'] %>
        <%= f.select :inches, [['Inches', nil], '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',                    
                                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :children %><br/>
        <%= f.select :children, [['Do you have or want kids?', nil], 'Yes, they live with me', 'I want kids now', 'I want one someday', 'Not for me']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :religion %><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['What is your faith?', nil], 'Agnostic', 'Atheist', 'Christian', 'Catholic', 'Buddhist', 'Hindu', 'Jewish', 'Muslim', 'Spiritual without affiliation', 'Other', 'None', 'Prefer not to say']%><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['How important is this to you?', nil], 'Very Important', 'Somewhat Important', 'Not Important']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :career %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :career %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :education %><br/>
        <%= f.select :education, [['What is your education level?', nil], 'High school', 'Some college', 'Undergraduate', "Bachelor's", "Master's ", 'PhD', 'Business school', 'Law school', 'Medical school' ]%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :ethnicity %><br/>
        <%= f.select :ethnicity, [['What is your ethnicity?', nil], 'Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other' ]%>
        </div>
        <%= f.label :user_drink %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_drink, [['How much do you drink?', nil], 'Often Drinks', 'Sometimes drinks', 'Never drinks', 'No comment' ]%>
        </div><br/>
        <%= f.label :user_smoke %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_smoke, [['How often do you smoke?', nil], 'Often smokes', 'Sometimes smokes', 'Never smokes'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

    <h3>About Me</h3>

    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :about_me %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :about_me %>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb (signup form):

## Sign Up

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :zip_code %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :birthday %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :birthday %>
    </div>
    <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `users_controller`:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now you have your `@user` available in the `show` view. So, you don't need a form, just:

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h2>Basics</h2>
  <p><%= @user.feet %></p>
  <p><%= @user.inches %></p>
  <p><%= @user.children %></p>
  <p><%= @user.religion %></p>
  ...
```

Also, resources will provide [7 routes by default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), so you can just create alias for some of than using `match`:

```
match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
match '/login',  :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

resources :users
resources :sessions
resources :password_resets
resources :galleries
resources :photos
```